# GCP Monitoring App Engine instance memory

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, monitoring

In Google Cloud Platform Monitoring, is there any way to monitor memory usage by App Engine instance? I see that there is the **Memory usage** metric for the **GAE Application** resource type, but I don't see a **Memory usage** metric for the **GAE Instance** resource type.

My particular use case is that I'd like to see (and make alerts based on) memory usage per instance.

Comment: Are you using App Engine Standard or Flex?

Comment: @Emmanuel Flex environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no built-in metric to monitor per instance memory. The only way to monitor the Memory Usage within a GAE Instance is by creating a custom metric, in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics) you can find more information about custom metrics.

Just remember that the amount of instances will increase according to the load, so a per instance alert shouldn't reflect the actual load of your application, that's why the memory usage is normally measured by group on the built in metric rather than per instance.

Comment: You're right that memory usage per instance wouldn't be helpful for monitoring total application load. It is still very helpful to be able to track how much memory an instance of an application uses for many other reasons.

Comment: I got it, the main trouble you may face is that the number of instances might depend on your load, so I recommend you to set a fixed amount by using [manual scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#manual-scaling)

Answer (score 0):

**Google Cloud Platform Monitoring** now supports Memory and CPU Utilisation metrics for **App Engine Flex**. See the full list of metrics here: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-appengine

Also, to visually explore the metrics, see the Cloud Monitoring **Metrics Explorer**: https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/metrics-explorer